# Does JSON allow positive sign for numbers?

Tags: json, grammar, number-formatting

After examining the JSON.org railroad (grammar) definition, the number definition provides the negative sign (-), but omits recognizing the positive (+) sign - is this an omission from the diagram, or does JSON disallow postitive sign (+) for numbers?

*The exponent allows optional positive (+) and negative (-) signs, so it would seem to save little to provide recognition of (+) for the number...*

Comment: What you want to do?

Comment: As part of a project to send/receive JSON from a web API, I was checking the JSON spec.  And I was surprised that the spec did not allow explicit positive (+) sign for numbers.

Comment: Its but obvious that positive number does not need any sign.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

Besides the grammar on [json.org](http://json.org/), JSON definitions are also provided by

- the [ECMAScript Language definition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), 5.1 Edition of June 2011
- [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) of March 2014

Concerning notation of signed numbers, they are all consistent. The former has

> JSONNumber ::  -? DecimalIntegerLiteral JSONFraction? ExponentPart?

while the latter says

> number = [ minus ] int [ frac ] [ exp ]

Also all of these specifications allow an optional plus sign in the exponent, but none permits a plus sign to precede the numeric literal.

Comment: Btw golang's json.Marshall func will fail trying to interpret an int with a preceding plus sign